# How can I set up this rule in Firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

hey that's my firestore database how can I set a rule to limit the access for each map field to its corresponding user?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do isn't possible.  You can't limit access to individual fields in a document.  A user is able to either read the entire document, or not read it at all.  What you should do is move each of those maps into subcollections named by the uid.  You can then write a rule to limit access to the subcollections by uid.

See the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-fields#allowing_read_access_only_for_specific_fields) for more details.

> Reads in Cloud Firestore are performed at the document level. You either retrieve the full document, or you retrieve nothing. There is no way to retrieve a partial document. It is impossible using security rules alone to prevent users from reading specific fields within a document.